# React Native app is using less secure cipher algorithm (com.securepreferences.SecurePreferencesOld)

Tags: android, react-native, android-security

When publishing Android app built in React Native, I got and error from automatic tests in Google Play Developer Console pointing [here](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/10046138)

How to fix this in React Native? Is this purely RN problem or some of my native modules doing this? I do not have any custom native code which is using `Cipher` class.

I am using those RN modules:

```
    "@kichiyaki/react-native-barcode-generator": "^0.6.7",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^12.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/installations": "^12.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "react-native-biometrics": "^2.1.4",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-mmkv-storage": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-send-intent": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-wallet-passes": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.6.5",
```

Comment: Did you find a fix? I'm assuming it's linked to react-native-mmkv-storage

Comment: I think it was caused by MMKV yea... I think I used another storage library.